# Asp.net NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, authentication, nullreferenceexception

I don't understand why it has thrown this error. The code seems fine to me, any can spot where I've gone wrong? I am trying to match the username and password from the database. Thanks

```
Line 20:         myData = loginservice.AdminGetUserTable();
Line 21: 
Line 22:         foreach (DataRow myRow in myData.Tables["Users"].Rows) 
Line 23:         {
Line 24:             if (txt_username.Text == myRow["Username"].ToString() && txt_password.Text == myRow["Password"].ToString())
```

The Error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\.NetProject\WebSite\Login.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553178
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: You never validate that `myData` actually contains anything...

Comment: @RichardBrown How do I validate this? Am still a beginner

Answer (score 0):

use try catch...may be you are not getting 'users' table. Use Tables[0] instead of Tables["Users"].
Use break points. There are many ways. Try any one

Answer (score 0):

here's all possibilities:

1. loginservice is null, or
2. myData is null, or
3. myData.Tables doesn't contain a table named "Users", thus it returns null, or
4. rows in the Users table don't contain a column named "Username", or
5. rows in the Users table don't contain a column named "Password"

Which one? - <strike>just match the error line number to your source code.</strike>

If your line 22 is really the line 22 mentioned in the error call stack,  then the "null" object must be myData or myData.Tables["Users"]

Comment: I've checked, everything u mentioned is correct :(. It the line 22 in code above

Comment: sorry - I missed the fact that you had line numbers. With the information you're providing it must be 2. or 3. from my response. I edited my answer to point to these two possibilities. Are you able to break in a debugger on that line? What do you see for myData.Tables["Users"]?